# Checking directory existence in Capistrano task fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've added new HDD to the server and need to use it to save all users info, so I need to move **public** directory to new HDD.

I don't know what is the best approach in my case, but I decided to change the public directory to be **symbolic link** pointing to new HDD path.

Based on that I created the below `capistrano task` to run after deploy:

```
  # I'm using capistrano 3.1
  namespace :public_to_symbolic do
    desc 'Change public directory to symbolic link pointing to other Hdd'
    task :change do
      on roles(:app) do
        is_directory = File.directory?("#{release_path}/public")
        is_symbolic_link = File.symlink?("#{release_path}/public")
        is_new_directory_exist = File.directory?('/mnt/newhdd/public')
        can_change = is_directory && !is_symbolic_link && is_new_directory_exist
        puts "is_directory : #{is_directory}" # prints false
        puts "is_symbolic_link : #{is_symbolic_link}" # prints false
        puts "is_new_directory_exist : #{is_new_directory_exist}" # prints false
        puts "can_change: #{can_change}" # prints false
        puts "release_path: #{release_path}" # prints /var/www/myapp/releases/20180305112922
        if can_change
          puts 'Changing public directory to symbolic link'
          execute "mv #{release_path}/public #{release_path}/public_linked"
          execute "ln -s /mnt/newhdd/public #{release_path}/public"
          execute "rm -rf #{release_path}/public_linked"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  after 'deploy', 'public_to_symbolic:change'
```

So, as commented, `is_directory`, `is_symbolic_link` and `is_new_directory_exist` are all returns `false`, but when I'm doing the same check (i.e `File.directory?("#{Rails.root}/public")` or `File.directory?("/var/www/myapp/current/public")`) using Rails console on deployment server, I'm getting `true` and I'm able to see the public directory!

To avoid this issue I tried also to use `current_path` instead of `release_path` but still same results.

I have two questions:

1. Why `is_directory` and `is_new_directory_exist` are always `false` while task is running?
2. If there is any better approach to use public directory on different Hdd, please advice.

All suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Ruby methods that you use in your Capistrano tasks run on your *local* machine.

For example:

- `File.directory?`
- `File.symlink?`

These are always evaluated on your local filesystem. Capistrano never runs Ruby code on the remote server. These methods always return `false` for you because they are trying to find e.g. `"#{release_path}/public"` on your local computer, which of course does not exist.

To run code on the server, the tools available to you are Capistrano's `test` and `execute` methods. These take in a command string that is executed remotely via SSH.

If you want to test if a remote path is a directory, you cannot use Ruby; you have to use something that can be run in a remote shell. Here is one way to test if a path is a directory, for example:

```
is_directory = test("[ -d #{release_path}/public ]")
```

Likewise, to test if a path is a symlink:

```
is_symbolic_link = test("[ -h #{release_path}/public ]")
```